# HackerEarth Challenge Find Maximum Taste of Fruits

Tags: python, algorithm, time-limit-exceeded

**Problem Statement:**

> Samu had got N fruits. Sweetness of ith fruit is given by A[i]. Now
>   she wants to eat all the fruits , in such a way that total taste is
>   maximised.
>
> Total Taste is calculated as follow (Assume fruits sweetness array
>   uses 1-based indexing) :
>
> ```
> int taste=0;
> for(int i=2;i<=N;i++){
>     if (A[i]-A[i-1] >= 0){
>        taste = taste + i*(A[i]-A[i-1]);
>     }
>     else{
>        taste = taste + i*(A[i-1]-A[i]);   
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> So, obviously the order in which she eat the fruits changes the Total
>   taste. She can eat the fruits in any order. Also once she start eating
>   a fruit she will finish that one before moving to some other fruit.
>
> Now she got confused in deciding the order in which she should eat
>   them so that her Total taste is maximized. So she ask for help from
>   you. Help her find the maximum taste she can have , if she can eat the
>   fruits in any order.
>
> **Input Format:**
>
> First line contain number of test cases T. First line of each test
>   case contains N, denoting the number of fruits. Next line contain N
>   space separated integers denoting the sweetness of each fruit.
>
> **Output Format:**
>
> For each test case you need to print the maximum taste Samu can have
>   by eating the fruits in any order she want to.
>
> **Constraints:**
>
> \$1 \le T \le 10\$   \$1 \le N \le 15\$
>
> Sweetness of each fruit, A[i] lies between 1 to 100 for 1 ≤ i ≤ N
>
> **Sample Input:**
>
> ```
> 1
> 3
> 2 5 4
> ```
>
> **Sample Output:**
>
> ```
> 13
> ```
>
> **Explanation:**
>
> ```
> [2,4,5] -> 2*(2) + 3*(1) = 7
> [2,5,4] -> 2*(3) + 3*(1) = 9
> [5,4,2] -> 2*(1) + 3*(2) = 8
> [5,2,4] -> 2*(3) + 3*(2) = 12
> [4,5,2] -> 2*(1) + 3*(3) = 11
> [4,2,5] -> 2*(2) + 3*(3) = 13
> ```
>
> The maximum is 13 that can be obtained by eating the fruits according to
>   sweetness order [4,2,5].

---

```
from itertools import permutations
for _ in xrange(int(raw_input())):
    n=int(raw_input())
    val=map(int,raw_input().split())
    max_ = 0
    for A in permutations(val):
        taste=0;
        for i in xrange(1,len(A)):
            taste = taste + (i+1)*abs(A[i]-A[i-1])
        max_= max(max_,taste)
    print max_
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are searching over the full set of permutations, which leads to a time complexity of \$O(n!)\$, which is rarely a good thing. This seems like the type of problem that would benefit from a dynamic programming approach. I don't find it entirely satisfactory, as it uses a top-down approach, but it is much more efficient than your implementation, so here it goes:

The basic idea is that, if you take a subset \$A\$ of \$m\$ items, and compute the \$m\$ values \$t_{A,j}\$, being the "best taste using the items in \$A\$ and ending in the \$j\$-th item, you can compute \$t_{A^*, m+1}\$, where \$A^*\$ is the set \$A\$ augmented with an extra item not in that set, easily. This is kind of confusing, I know, but below I am indexing memoized solutions by `(items_remaining_to_be_used, last_item_used)`, and building the total taste by adding one of the remaining items at a time. It may be easier to look at the code:

```
def top_down(seq):
    memo = {}
    for idx, item in enumerate(seq):
        key = (frozenset(seq[:idx] + seq[idx+1:]), item)
        memo[key] = 0
    mult = 1
    best_taste = None
    while best_taste is None:
        mult += 1
        new_memo = {}
        for (items, last), taste in memo.items():
            items = list(items)
            for idx, item in enumerate(items):
                new_taste = taste + mult * abs(item - last)
                new_set = frozenset(items[:idx] + items[idx+1:])
                if not new_set:
                    best_taste = max(new_taste,
                                     0 if best_taste is None else best_taste)
                else:
                    new_key = new_set, item
                    new_memo[new_key] = max(new_memo.get(new_key, 0),
                                            new_taste)
        memo = new_memo
    return best_taste
```

Comparing to a function implementing your naive approach:

```
def naive(seq):
    best_taste = 0
    for perm in permutations(seq):
        taste = 0
        for idx, (this, that) in enumerate(zip(perm[:-1], perm[1:])):
            taste += (idx + 2) * abs(this - that)
        best_taste = max(best_taste, taste)
    return best_taste
```

The timing differences start out small:

```
a = [random.randint(100) for _ in range(5)]
%timeit naive(a)
1000 loops, best of 3: 215 µs per loop
%timeit top_down(a)
1000 loops, best of 3: 262 µs per loop
```

But things soon favor the `top_down` implementation massively:

```
a = [random.randint(100) for _ in range(10)]
%timeit naive(a)
1 loops, best of 3: 10.4 s per loop
%timeit top_down(a)
10 loops, best of 3: 44.6 ms per loop
```

That's over a 200x improvement! And of course:

```
>>> naive(a) == top_down(a)
True
```

And even the largest problem in your challenge can be solved in a reasonable amount of time, not sure if it will be fast enough though:

```
a = [random.randint(100) for _ in range(15)]
%timeit top_down(a)
1 loops, best of 3: 3.76 s per loop
```